# Getting issue-Unsupported Method: GET in postman while testing API Gateway API

Tags: postman, aws-api-gateway

I configured HTTP endpoint in API Gateway and tested in API Gateway. It got succeeded. While I am trying to test stage URL(after performing deploy) from Postman, getting issue Unsupported Method: GET. Can anyone help on this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Above error we can see because of two possible issues

1) The error you're seeing is because the call required "https://" and you are runing on "http://"

2) You are try to call POST,PUT,DELETE  method using GET call

Try to update Cors rule and test again

```
<CORSRule> 
   <AllowedHeader>*</AllowedHeader>
```

Comment: Can you run on chrome and check developer option F12 , what error you are getting ?

Comment: I need to give few parameters as input, so I opted postman to test.

Comment: Enable Cors on API getway and test again